# TypeError: f2() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

My code

```
class MyClass:
    i =123

    def f2(a):
        global b
        print (a)
        print (b)
        b = 9

x = MyClass()
x.f2(1)
```

It does not work as expected

```
TypeError: f2() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Why? How to inspect function and positional arguments?
If I change

```
x.f2()
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fb3f028fbe0>
9
```

In this case I can not pass a.

Comment: **TypeError: f2() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given** You are providing  `x(self)` and `1`

Comment: Abdul,take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the 'OOP' reasons to create functions inside a class are inheriting constructors.

You've created the class 'MyClass' and the function f2() is one of the functions inside it.

To convey that the function belongs to/ is a part of the class, you have to pass a default parameter 'self' in the function or it is not recognized by the interpreter.

Coming to your error:
You are passing 1 to the function, but by default there is a 'self' passed to all the class functions. Two solutions possible,

1. Either make the function static by the decorator

   ```
   @static

   def f2(a):

       pass
   ```

   *this conveys that the function is just inside the class but 
   doesn't belong to it. It just is there.
2. pass a 'self' in the function.

   ```
   def f2(self, a):
       pass
   ```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass:
    i =123

    def f2(self,a):
        print (a)

x = MyClass()
x.f2(1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass:
    i =123
    def f2(self,a):
        global b
        print (a)
        print (b)
        b = 9
```

write as this ,you will work ok